# click on key during the Call on android

Tags: android, events, call

hey i want to press 1 or 2 during the call. as example when you call a call center and want press 1 key to go to sales department without click this number by your hand, but i want to click it problematically during the Call.

Now i can invoke keypress and handle the call events but it doesn't work.

```
PhoneStateListener myCallListener = new PhoneStateListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            // the variable incomingNumber holds the number calling.
            // the state variable holds the state of the phone (Ringing, Idle ...)
              switch (state) {
              case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                  Log.e("Incoming_call", incomingNumber+" is calling me ...");
                  break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                    KeyEvent eventDown = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1);
                    dispatchKeyEvent(eventDown);
                  // your logic here, right now the incoming caller is logged.
                  Log.e("Out Call", incomingNumber+" is calling me ...");
                break;
                default:
                break;
            }
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
           }
        };
        TelephonyManager phoneManager = (TelephonyManager) 
        this.getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        phoneManager.listen(myCallListener,
        PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to programmatically make a call, and add DTMF tones and pauses as needed:

```
Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL",Uri.parse("tel://" + number + ',' + dtmf));
```

It is not possible to decide in the middle of the call to insert DTMF tones into the audio uplink, although it is a [requested feature](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1428).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is going to generate a key down event for **your** activity, not for the Phone application.

As far as I know, it is impossible to achieve what you want, but I could be wrong. However, if it was possible, it's a potential issue, as any application could then send any touchtones during a phone call and trigger bad things without the user be aware.